# How to merge generic list of objects?

Tags: typescript

I want to combine/merge any number of objects and keep type safety. Here's what I have so far:

```
function combine(...args) {
  return (<any>Object).assign({}, ...args);
}

const foobar = combine(
  { foo: 1 },
  { bar: 2 }
);

console.log(foobar); // {foo: 1, bar: 2}
```

The problem is that foobar is of type `any`. I can get type safety for a known number of arguments, not any. Here's the solution for 2 arguments:

```
function combine<T, U>(a: T, b: U): T & U {
  return (<any>Object).assign({}, a, b);
}
```

I was trying to make `function combine<T extends any[]>(...args: T)` work but not getting anywhere.

Note: `(<any>Object)` is to work around `error TS2339: Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'`

Comment: `'assign' does not exist...`: You are probably not loading the libraries for ES2015 or later.  If your target environment is ES5, then `Object.assign` really doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trick with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to take a union of types and get an intersection of those types:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
```

Assuming you're using TS 3.0, the following typing should work:

```
declare function combine<T extends any[]>(...args: T): UnionToIntersection<T[number]>;
```

Let's test it:

```
const foobar = combine(
  { foo: 1 },
  { bar: 2 }
);
// { foo: number } & { bar: number }
```

Looks good, I think.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!